# Pandas retrieve the index of added row from resampling

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, resampling

I have a dataframe with missing rows that I interpolate and resample. I would like to know if there was a way to grab the index of the rows that are added to the dataframe when I resample it ?

This is how I create/resample/interpolate the dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import *

# Create df and drop a few rows
rng = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=365, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng)) },index = rng)
df = df.drop([datetime(2000,1,5),datetime(2000,1,24)])

df = df.resample('D').interpolate(method='linear')
```

Comment: `df_new.index.difference(df_old.index)` should do it - as long as you don't replace the variable

Comment: That works very well, thank you ! Do you want to put it as an answer ? I can accept it and you get reputation points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the additional index elements by taking the [difference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) between the new and the old ones

```py
In [16]: df_new = df.resample('D').interpolate(method='linear')

In [17]: df_new.index.difference(df.index)
Out[17]: DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-05', '2000-01-24'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```