# Missing data range Pandas dataframe comparison Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, time

How would I be able to write a code that outputs the differences between `dates` and `data`.   There are missing data points in the `data` code  where there is a skip in the `dates` data frame of the 1 minute timeframe. For example after `2015-10-08 13:53:00` there are 6 data points that are missing so it prints it as `'2015-10-08 13:54:00', '2015-10-08 14:00:00'` outputs the range of missing `data`. records it in the 2 dimensional array down in The `Expected Output`. How would I be able to code a function that results in the Expected Output.

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime 

dates = pd.date_range("2015-10-08 13:40:00", "2015-10-08 14:12:00", freq="1min")
data = pd.to_datetime(['2015-10-08 13:41:00',
               '2015-10-08 13:42:00', '2015-10-08 13:43:00',
               '2015-10-08 13:44:00', '2015-10-08 13:45:00',
               '2015-10-08 13:46:00', '2015-10-08 13:47:00',
               '2015-10-08 13:48:00', '2015-10-08 13:49:00',
               '2015-10-08 13:50:00', '2015-10-08 13:51:00',
               '2015-10-08 13:52:00', '2015-10-08 13:53:00',
               '2015-10-08 13:54:00', '2015-10-08 14:01:00',
               '2015-10-08 14:02:00', '2015-10-08 14:03:00',
               '2015-10-08 14:04:00', '2015-10-08 14:05:00',
               '2015-10-08 14:06:00', '2015-10-08 14:07:00',
               '2015-10-08 14:10:00', '2015-10-08 14:11:00',
               '2015-10-08 14:12:00'])
```

Expected Output:

```
[['2015-10-08 13:40:00'], 
 ['2015-10-08 13:54:00', '2015-10-08 14:00:00'],
 ['2015-10-08 14:08:00', '2015-10-08 14:09:00']]
```

Comment: This question was more or less answered 20 mins ago.  Convert to `DatetimeIndex` and use the `difference` function  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69775788/pandas-retrieve-the-index-of-added-row-from-resampling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dates` and `data` here are both datetimeindexes. You can take the difference of these using `pd.Index.difference`

```py
In [55]: s = pd.Series(dates.difference(data))
    ...: s # sort if needed
Out[55]:
0   2015-10-08 13:40:00
1   2015-10-08 13:55:00
2   2015-10-08 13:56:00
3   2015-10-08 13:57:00
4   2015-10-08 13:58:00
5   2015-10-08 13:59:00
6   2015-10-08 14:00:00
7   2015-10-08 14:08:00
8   2015-10-08 14:09:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [56]: groups_diff_ne_1min = s.diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=60)) != pd.Timedelta(seconds=60)
    ...: groups_diff_ne_1min
Out[56]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
dtype: bool

In [57]: groups = groups_diff_ne_1min.cumsum()
    ...: groups
Out[57]:
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    2
8    2
dtype: int64

In [58]: s.groupby(groups).agg(['first', 'last'])
Out[58]:
                first                last
0 2015-10-08 13:40:00 2015-10-08 13:40:00
1 2015-10-08 13:55:00 2015-10-08 14:00:00
2 2015-10-08 14:08:00 2015-10-08 14:09:00
```

Comment: Thank you that works, is there also a way to show how many data points are missing between each range like `[1, 6, 2]`.

Comment: sure, add `'size'` to the agg list